# How to populate blanks in a column with last non-blank cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet of data on Google Sheets where one order is spread over several rows, however, only the first row contains all the information. I need a way to copy the last populated cell down into all of the blanks.

So it looks like the left, but I need it to do what's on the right:

```
GB    GB
-     GB
AU    AU
-     AU
-     AU
```

I've tried every formula I could find online, but they all either don't work or require pasting into every blank cell. This spreadsheet could reach 20,000+ rows, so I really need a formula that will do this automatically. I don't mind if it duplicates the whole column into a new column using an `ARRAYFORMULA`, I just need it to contain all the correct data.

**To summarise, I want a formula that will take an entire column of a spreadsheet and populate every blank cell with the value in the last populated cell above it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A) <= MAX(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)), ROW(A2:A))),
 VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), FILTER({ROW(A2:A), A2:A}, LEN(A2:A)), 2), ))
```

[image: 0]

or remove `NOT`

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly and does exactly what I wanted! I've been trying to sort this for 2 days with no luck and you did it in 10 minutes - thank you very much.